# How to do occlusion culling in world space

Tags: graphics

How to do occlusion culling in world space?

Yesterday I did interview with game dev company.

Interviewer asked me "What is advantage of Occlusion culling before in Screen space"
Maybe he think occlusion culling in world space.

But I didn't know can do occlusion culling in world space.

How to do that?

Comment: "Occlusion Culling" isn't a single technique or algorithm, it is a board generic _category_ of approaches and algorithms. One can argue that quake's BSP tree approach is a form of occlusion culling, and both creating (in pre-processing) and traversing (at runtime) the tree is done is world space.

Comment: @derhass: If that answers the question you should post it as an answer.  In general, questions should not be answered in comments.